# Aframe object not loading

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to load an object via AFRAME-React

```
  let modelAttributes = {
   obj: '#' + id + '_obj',
   mtl: '#' + id + '_mtl',
 }

return(
   <Entity  {...commonAttribute}>
    <a-entity obj-model={modelAttributes}></a-entity>
</Entity>
```

)

The assets are there in the asset manager

```
<a-asset-item id="hotspot869_obj" src="/cdn/hotspot_869_MODEL_530b2710-15d4-11e8-817d-45ca437b9a19.obj" preload="auto"></a-asset-item>
<a-asset-item id="hotspot869_mtl" src="/cdn/hotspot_869_MODEL_aaf40910-15d4-11e8-899b-93b7b4edc285.mtl" preload="auto"></a-asset-item>
```

I get a load of warnings

```
core:schema:warn Unknown property `0` for component/system `obj-model`.
```

Any ideas why my model isn't loading?

EDIT it loads if I do

```
 return( <Entity  {...commonAttribute} obj-model={modelAttributes}>)
```

But I do need it to have a parent container, any ideas why this would be?

Comment: You don’t have valid URLs in your src attributes. `http://...` Try without React first too and see if your template thing is the problem

Comment: They're relative URLs.. do you mean because of the / ?

Comment: According to the browser the files have loaded OK. That's not the problem.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrapped it in an entity.

The problem was there was no scale value.. an meaningful error would be helpful.